# Calculate Payback Value in Excel

Tags: excel, finance

I have a set of values as following in a row:

(9,888,000)  (88,410,205)   (76,030,786)    (62,712,494)    (48,416,610)     (33,102,893) (16,729,517)  746,979      19,371,753      39,191,722      43,755,624     66,114,081   89,819,671      114,926,989  141,492,724

Each value represents some amount in a specific year. e.g.(16,729,517) is the cash outflow in year 7.

Now I've an amount of 110,000,000 as the initial payment in another cell.

Now i try to calculate payback year of initial payment. For me payback period should be: 7.96 as in that year amount becomes positive.

But I'm unable to calculate this 7.96 value. can anyone please help?

i've done it via indirect method:

as first step I check value in each column and store true or false against positive and negative values.

2nd Step: `=MATCH(TRUE,Complete Array,0)`. This gives me 8 as Digit, where it finds first positive value.

Then, as third step, i use this formula:

```
=Year-OFFSET(CFC,0,Year)/OFFSET(Investment,0,Year) .
```

in this case Year is what i got in step 2. and CFC cell is empty (Cumulative Cash Flow in 0 year). Out put of this 7.96, which is my required value.

But this is a lengthy and indirect way. I want to have a one line formula for all these calculations.

Comment: Show us how you have tried to solve this problem, and where you have run into problems.

Comment: RON" i've done it via indirect method:

Comment: Add that information and describe your method with formula in your question.  It would seem like a simple interpolation problem.

Comment: RON... i've done it via indirect method: as first step I check value in each column and store true or false against positive and negative values. then i use this formula: =MATCH(TRUE,Complete Array,0). This gives me 8 as Digit, where it finds first positive value. Then, as third step, i use this formula:=Year-OFFSET(CFC,0,Year)/OFFSET(Investment,0,Year) .  in this case Year is what i got in step 2. and CFC cell is empty (Cumulative Cash Flow in 0 year). But this is a lengthy and indirect way. I want to have a one line formula for all these calculations.

Comment: Have you considered a VBA solution?

Comment: No. I just want a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your formula into a single line.  Here's a slight variation on what you are doing, which is a straight line extrapolation between the values below and above zero:

```
=FORECAST(0,{-1,0},
OFFSET(CashFlows,,MATCH(TRUE,CashFlows>0,0)-2,1,2))
+MATCH(TRUE,CashFlows>0,0)
```

You may need to change the offset formula if your `CashFlows` range is in a column instead of a row.  The formula is entered as an array formula by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`

**EDIT** This formula ignores the very first cash flow whether positive or negative.  If you want to include it, change the `>` operator to `>=` and test for an error.

Comment: I get 'N/A' when i try to use : MATCH(TRUE,CashFlows>0,0).

Comment: That is only a part of the formula.  But did you enter it as I wrote in my answer?  By holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`?  If you observe the formula in the formula bar, are there braces `{...}` around it added by Excel?  (not by you)

Comment: Actually I had same result "N/A" for complete formula and then i tried to do it in parts. also i don't see any {...} in formula bar.... For reference, I've uploaded file on : http://we.tl/hGYUVYGr1j sheet 1 by name of '20'.

Comment: Let me try a third time: **ENTER THE FORMULA BY HOLDING DOWN `CTRL+SHIFT` WHILE HITTING `ENTER`**  If you do this correctly you will see the `{...}` around the formula in the formula bar.

Comment: Got {..} in formula bar...yet result is same...'N/A'

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem.  When I select, on the file you uploaded, cell E31, where the formula is located, and enter it properly, it returns a value of 8.640301055 which seems to be correct.  (Your modified formula in E32 returns `#N/A`, but I would expect that given the modifications you made).

Comment: Got it this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula approach seems natural. I am not sure that you can do much better then what you are doing, although I'm sure that an array-formula guru could find a way to wrap it all into a single, albeit not-quite readable formula.

Using VBA you can write a function which can be called directly from the spreadsheet. In a standard code module put:

```
Function PayBack(R As Range) As Variant
    'R is a range, assumed to be 1-dimensional
    'consisting of negative numbers which
    'at some point transition to positive
    'returns the cross-over point

    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim x As Double, y As Double

    n = R.Cells.Count
    x = R.Cells(1).Value
    If x >= 0 Then
        PayBack = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If

    'x < 0 in the following loop:

    For i = 2 To n
        y = R.Cells(i).Value
        If y >= 0 Then
            x = Abs(x)
            PayBack = i - y / (x + y)
            Exit Function
        End If
        x = y
    Next i
    'if the code reaches here -- still negative, so return error
    PayBack = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Then it could be used like:

[image]

I have your sample data in row 1 (so A1:O1) and in A3 I just entered the formula

```
=PayBack(A1:O1)
```

and it computes as expected. It returns `#N/A` error if there is no negative to positive transition in the data -- though that can of course be tweaked in various ways.